# Type Error in tensorflow 2.0 while using tf.keras.layer.RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I found out error occured because return format of the tensorflow.dynamic_rnn(deprecated) and keras.layers.LSTM are different.
So I have changed almost every code, and it works fine.
Anyway thanks for your comment :)

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
    
train_x = [[[1], [2], [5], [6]],
           [[5], [7], [7], [8]],
           [[3], [4], [5], [7]]]
train_y = [[[1], [3], [7], [11]],
           [[5], [12], [14], [15]],
           [[3], [7], [9], [12]]]

test_x = [[[1], [2], [3], [4]],
          [[4], [5], [6], [7]]]
actual_y = [[[1], [3], [5], [7]],
            [[4], [9], [11], [13]]]

layer_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(4,1),name='input')
layer_rnn = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, return_sequences=True, name='RNN')(layer_input)
layer_output = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),name='output')(layer_rnn)

model = tf.keras.Model(layer_input, layer_output)
#print(model.summary())

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model._name='many_to_many'

model.fit(train_x,train_y,epochs=1000,batch_size=1, verbose=0)
print(model.predict(train_x))
print(model.predict(test_x))
#result of the test is almost same
```

---

I'm totally new in tensorflow. So I'm studying with the book written by Nishant Shukla. Since the version of the tensorflow has been changed, some codes do not working.
Below is the code. How can I fix this problem?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_eager_execution()

class SeriesPredictor:
    def __init__(self,input_dim=1, seq_size=4, hidden_dim =10):
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.seq_size = seq_size
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.W_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_dim,1]), name='W_out')
        self.b_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name='b_out')
        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, seq_size, input_dim])
        self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, seq_size])

        self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.model()-self.y))
        self.train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimizer(self.cost)

        self.saver = tf.train.Saver()

    def model(self):
        cell = tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(self.hidden_dim)
        outputs, states = tf.keras.layers.RNN(cell, self.x, dtype=tf.float32)
        #since some codes was changed between tf v1 and v2, inevitably add keras code
        num_examples = tf.shape(self.x)[0]
        W_repeated = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(self.W_out,0),[num_examples,1,1])
        out = tf.matmul(outputs,W_repeated)+self.b_out
        out = tf.squeeze(out)
        return out

    def train(self, train_x, train_y):
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
            sess.run(tf.global_varaibles_initializer())
            for i in range(1000):
                _, mse = sess.run([self.train_op, self.cost], feed_dict={self.x:train_x,self.y:train_y})
                if i % 1000 == 0:
                    print(i, mse)
            save_path = self.saver.save(sess,'./model.ckpt')
            print('Model saved to {}'.format(save_path))

    def test(self,test_x):
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
            self.saver.restore(sess,'./model.ckpt')
            output = sess.run(self.model(), feed_dict={self.x:test_x})
            print(output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    predictor = SeriesPredictor(input_dim = 1, seq_size = 4, hidden_dim = 10)
    train_x = [[[1],[2],[5],[6]],
               [[5],[7],[7],[8]],
                [[3],[4],[5],[7]]]
    train_y = [[1,3,7,11],
               [5,12,14,15],
               [3,7,9,12]]
    predictor.train(train_x=train_x, train_y=train_y)
    test_x = [[[1],[2],[3],[4]],
              [[4],[5],[6],[7]]]
    actual_y = [[[1],[3],[5],[7]],
                [[4],[9],[11],[13]]]
    pred_y = predictor.test(test_x)
    print(pred_y)
```

Comment: What version of TF was this written for? Can you more explicitly mark the lines that you have added yourself or post yours and theirs separately?

Comment: You are not giving any input to the RNN layer, that is why it errors.